# vbscript subtracting decimal values

Tags: vbscript

vbscript math function : FormatNumber

```
FormatNumber(4.33 - 4.28, 1, -2, -2, -2) //answer 0.0
FormatNumber(0.05, 1, -2, -2, -2)        //answer 0.1
```

even

```
FormatNumber(cdbl(4.33) - cdbl(4.28), 1, -2, -2, -2) //answer 0.0
```

but

```
FormatNumber(4.34 - 4.28,1,-2,-2,-2) //answer 0.1
```

Why is it not rounded correctly? How can I fix this?

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem? This question is illegible.

Comment: @CodyGray i want to formant a decimal number so that there will be one digit after the decimal. But the resulting values are different as you can see in my question though '4.33 - 4.28' is '0.05'

Comment: This has to do with the fact you are working with floats. [This](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-does-3-2-1-5-4-7000000000000002.html) was the best resource I could find this quick. Must be ones that better explain the problem. Try the following to see the _problem_: `Response.Write 4.33 - 4.28`

Answer (score 2):

Floating point numbers in computers are but an approximation of mathematical (real life?) numbers.

```
>> WScript.Echo (4.33 - 4.28)
>>
4,99999999999998E-02
>> WScript.Echo 0.5
>>
0,5
>> WScript.Echo CStr(((4.33 - 4.28) = 0.05))
>>
False
```

There are lot's of explanations about how and why numbers are  represented and manipulated; just use Wikipedia or Google to get started.

See [one example here](http://floating-point-gui.de/) (complete with xkcd!).